# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Tags: c#

I currently have a Generic method that reads an Value from the database based on a key and returns a specific type of that value.

```
    public T Get<T>(string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        var myparms = new List<SqlParameter>
                      {
                          new SqlParameter("@KEY", key),
                      };
        const string getPropertyQuery = "SELECT SPARM_VALUE FROM SYSPARAMS WHERE SPARM_KEY = @KEY;";

        var returnedValue = //Get value from Database

        if (returnedValue == null)
        {
            return defaultValue; //Value does not exists so return default.
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(returnedValue, typeof(T));
    }
```

But when I try and return a TimeSpan type I get the following exception. `Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'.`

After a bit of googling I found that the most common solution is to use the `TimeSpan.Parse` or `TimeSpan.TryParse` methods.

I also found [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) Structure.

`public struct TimeSpan : IComparable, IComparable, 
    IEquatable, IFormattable`

My question is why, why is TimeSpan not able to do this. Is it because it doesn't have the `IConvertible` interface? Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't think `Convert.ChangeType` is what you really want. Try `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom`:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
return converter.CanConvertFrom(returnedValue) ? 
    (T)converter.ConvertFrom(returnedValue) :
    defaultValue;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I thought Convert.ChangeType actually made use of TypeConverters. Ah, I see it only uses `IConvertable`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit cast/conversion defined between `string` and `TimeSpan` because most strings are not `TimeSpan`s.

If the framework defined such a cast, would you also expect these to exist on `DateTime` and all other value types?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why there isn't a Convert.ToTimeSpan method? I understand that not all value types have casts but I just find it strange that the Convert class doesn't included TimeSpan.

Comment: @Jethro - Probably because it is not used as much as others. And the `Convert` class already has many overloads - adding more would just add to this mass of methods.

Answer (score 1):

There isnt an implicit conversion between `String` and `TimeSpan`, you need to convert explicitly using `Parse` or `TryParse`